# Electron Typescript Material-UI withStyles error TS2694: Namespace '".../node_modules/csstype/index"' has no exported member 'FontFace'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, electron

I'm not new to Material-UI, though I am new to Electron and using React, Typescript, Material-UI with it.

I've been getting this error when I've been trying to make an electron boilerplate code for myself to easily start off a project with later. I'm not running into any issues when I've been installing one dependency after another and using them -- Material-UI had no issue when I first installed it to the project and created the boilerplate code. When I got everything the way I wanted for the base I deleted the .cache, dist, parcel-dist, and node_modules folders to reduce the size of the boilerplate for it to be used later.

When I try to copy and reuse it afterward, I get the error:

```
[electron] node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.d.ts(10,24): error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Documents/Projects/Node.js/Typescript/Electron/Material-UI Sidebar Template/node_modules/csstype/index"' has no exported member 'FontFace'.
```

```
[electron] node_modules/@material-ui/styles/withStyles/withStyles.d.ts(10,53): error TS2694: Namespace '"D:/Documents/Projects/Node.js/Typescript/Electron/Material-UI Sidebar Template/node_modules/csstype/index"' has no exported member 'FontFace'.
```

If I just run `tsc` instead of trying to run the electron app, I still get that same error.

Here are different files that may help:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "electron-react-typescript-template",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Electron React boilerplate",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel src/index.html --out-dir parcel-dist",
    "build": "parcel build src/index.html --out-dir dist/parcel-build --public-url ./",
    "dev": "concurrently -k \"npm start\" \"npm:electron\"",
    "electron": "wait-on tcp:1234 && tsc && electron .",
    "make": "npm build && tsc && electron-builder",
    "release": "npm build && tsc && electron-builder --publish=always",
    "publish": "npm build && electron-forge publish",
    "lint": "eslint --ext .ts .",
    "stop": "taskkill -F -IM node.exe"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "build": {
    "files": [
      "dist/**/*",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "directories": {
      "output": "./out"
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        {
          "target": "nsis",
          "arch": [
            "x64",
            "ia32"
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "category": "Utility",
      "target": "deb"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "electron-is-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-serve": "^1.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.14.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc": "^2.0.0-alpha.3",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.20",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.9",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^2.18.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^2.18.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.6",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "electron": "^13.1.7",
    "electron-builder": "^22.11.7",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.24.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.25.1",
    "parcel-bundler": "1.12.5",
    "postcss-modules": "3.2.2",
    "sass": "^1.37.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.2",
    "wait-on": "^6.0.0"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./src/*"],
      "*": ["node_modules/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
    "electron/**/*"
  ]
}
```

Instance of what I'm using withStyles for:
NavigationDrawer.tsx

```
import React from 'react';

import { AppBar, createStyles, CssBaseline, Drawer, IconButton, Theme, Toolbar, WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import MenuIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Menu';
import CloseIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Close';

import { ModalProps } from '@material-ui/core';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/styles/index';

import { NavigationWidth } from '~/constants/ContentConstants';
import { IconList } from './IconList';




const styles = (theme: Theme) => ({
    sidebar: {
        width: NavigationWidth.CLOSED,
        height: '100%',
        left: 0,
        top: 0,
        zIndex: 1
    },
    menuIcon: {
        flex: 1
    }
})




interface NavigationDrawerProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
    isDrawerOpen: boolean;
    toggleDrawer: () => void
}

class _NavigationDrawer extends React.Component<NavigationDrawerProps> {

    toggleDrawer: ModalProps['onClose'] = (event, reason) => {
        console.log('Toggle Drawer')
        this.props.toggleDrawer();
    }

    render() {
        const { isDrawerOpen } = this.props;

        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div>
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <AppBar className={this.props.classes.sidebar} id='sidebar'>
                        <Toolbar variant='dense'>
                            <IconButton className={this.props.classes.menuIcon} edge={isDrawerOpen ? 'start' : 'start'} onClick={this.props.toggleDrawer}>
                                { isDrawerOpen ? <CloseIcon /> : <MenuIcon /> }
                            </IconButton>
                        </Toolbar>
                        <IconList isDrawerOpen={isDrawerOpen} />
                    </AppBar>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }
}

export const NavigationDrawer = withStyles(styles)(_NavigationDrawer)
```

One thing I'm unsure if it's related, is I do import some custom fonts locally, which I'm unsure if that is what's triggering this issue or not -- or if it's conflicting with Material-UI; though, it works fine until I delete the folders I mentioned. I import them in CSS, and link them in the index.html like so:

index.css

```
@font-face {
  font-family: RobotoCondensed;
  src: url(assets/roboto-condensed.light.ttf);
  font-weight: 800;
}

@font-face {
  font-family: EconomicaBold;
  src: url(assets/economica-bold.ttf);
}
```

EDIT: It seems to be mainly a problem when my `dev` script is running `tsc`

Answer (score 0):

You somehow get an old version of csstype in node_modules. Use `npm ls csstype` and figure out why. It should be v3 installed.

If you install it manually it should be resolved `npm install csstype --save-dev` but it's better to find a solution to the real dependency problem instead.

Comment: It seems that @material-ui requires only 2.6.18, though react requires 3.0.9. However, manually installing it as you suggested doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: That right, csstype for @material-ui was upgraded here https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/commit/d7b605193ea59f65f9fbba3b206513b260ddb945 so you need to upgrade to @material-ui@5.